# Right way to make a donation button in desktop application which will navigate a user to the paypal website

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, paypal

Is it possible to place a donation button of paypal in windows form desktop application.

I have a website where I will host my desktop application but I want to make a donation button in the about box of the application, I don't want to make any transaction on my winform app using an api because of security purposes. 
I read somewhere that I can create a link label and place that in the application. 
My Question is that what should be the right way to make a button which will navigate a user to the paypal website for transaction purposes. I have a verified premiere account.

**[Edited - Donate button ?]**
Screen-shot of what i am getting in the options , there's no Donate button..
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this website by simply googling.This explains how to do this in a c# application.
http://www.gorancic.com/blog/net/c-paypal-donate-button

This is the exact code on there:

```
  private void btnDonate_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "";

        string business     = "my@paypalemail.com";  // your paypal email
        string description  = "Donation";            // '%20' represents a space. remember HTML!
        string country      = "AU";                  // AU, US, etc.
        string currency     = "AUD";                 // AUD, USD, etc.

        url += "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" +
            "?cmd=" + "_donations" +
            "&business=" + business +
            "&lc=" + country +
            "&item_name=" + description +
            "&currency_code=" + currency +
            "&bn=" + "PP%2dDonationsBF";

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
    }
```

Be sure to type the URL right, because if u don't it wont work(of course) :D

You will get this page after clicking the button:
[image]

Comment: Thanks ! but i also read somewhere that we have to place paypal logo with button for using paypal services..i want to confirm that, is it legal to redirect users this way ?

Comment: I don't think it's illegal, but you can always ask if it is, on the paypal community forum.
They probably know it better than me :)

Comment: right ;) , actually just tried making a button .. there are three options - add to cart ,subscriptions and buy now . but no donation button , do you know why it is so ?

Comment: another thing that might help you, wich is almost the same: http://tabtheangrybadger.blogspot.nl/2013/03/c-create-paypal-donate-button-inside.html

Comment: Process.start is fine , i can redirect the users to the paypal site but the main issue is "Donate" button , it is not showing in the paypal button option..

Comment: Why do u want another button? the button is already in your winforms application...??

Comment: right ! there's a small concern, i have read somewhere that it's paypal policy that you can not create your own button for paypal redirection. Is it true or i can create my own button ?

Comment: As I said before, I really do not know this I'm just a developer :D
The best place for this question would be the Paypal community forum.

Comment: MColloard , I saw lot of questions posted there , no one replies there .. so ;) .. i placed button on my web page